# Get rid of duplicate polygons using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, wfs, mapserver, duplication, ms4w

OpenLayers 6, Mapserver 7

---

I have defined a vector source like this :

```
const presc = new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  loader: function(extent, resolution, projection, success, failure) {
     // let proj = projection.getCode();
     let url = 'http://xxxx/cgi-bin/mapserv.exe?MAP=c:/ms4w/Apache/site/mapfile/naasp_ol.map&service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=emprise_3857&outputFormat=geojson&SRSNAME=EPSG:3857&' + 
                'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',' + 'EPSG:3857'
     let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('GET', url);
     let onError = function() {
       presc.removeLoadedExtent(extent);
       failure();
     }
     xhr.onerror = onError;
     xhr.onload = function() {
       if (xhr.status == 200) {
         let features = presc.getFormat().readFeatures(xhr.responseText);
         console.log(features)
         presc.addFeatures(features);
         
         success(features);
       } else {
         onError();
       }
     }
     xhr.send();
   },
   strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
 });
```

and the vector layer :

```
const prescLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: presc,
});
```

The WFS is based on a `PostGis` view having 'id' as a unique field.

`console.log(features)` returns an array with a correct number of features each time the extent changes. But features are duplicated in the map!

I did not find recent posts with this issue. I did not go anywhere with these old ones  [OL3...](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193300/ol3-data-from-wfs-is-added-multiple-times) and [OpenLayers strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222503/openlayers-bbox-strategy).

[image: example]

Comment: Are you showing `feature.getId()` or `feature.get('id')`?

Comment: I guess you mean in the label? `feature.get('id')`

Comment: That is a property but not the unique id.  To set that try inserting`features.forEach(function(feature)[feature.setId(feature.get('id');});` before calling `addFeatures`

Comment: that's it. Thanks. To be sure  with this,I create a unique id different from the one used for the label?

Comment: The GeoJSON spec allows an `id` property directly in the feature object, which is independent of one with the same key inside the `properties` object, but in your case it should be given the same value.  It may also be possible to configure a server to set `id` in the feature object.

Comment: Thanks for using MS4W, great to see it in action here!  PS. please consider hiding the `map=` mapfile path from your WFS service.  See my related answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73200841/mapserver-hide-the-map-parameter-map-path